# Shorten multiple elseifs in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, strpos

So I want to display an image depending on what a string contains, and I have multiple elseifs? I have shortened it down a bit, but this is currently 50+ lines. I am thinking there must be a cleaner way to do this?

```
   <?php if(strpos(' '.$this->escape($title).' ', '25% off')){$imgsrc = '25percentoff.png';}
        elseif(strpos(' '.$this->escape($title).' ', '24% off')){$imgsrc = '24percentoff.png';}
        elseif(strpos(' '.$this->escape($title).' ', '23% off')){$imgsrc = '23percentoff.png';}
        elseif(strpos(' '.$this->escape($title).' ', '22% off')){$imgsrc = '22percentoff.png';}
        elseif(strpos(' '.$this->escape($title).' ', '21% off')){$imgsrc = '21percentoff.png';}
        elseif(strpos(' '.$this->escape($title).' ', '20% off')){$imgsrc = '20percentoff.png';}
        elseif(strpos(' '.$this->escape($title).' ', '19% off')){$imgsrc = '19percentoff.png';}
        else{$imgsrc = 'default.png';}
   ?>
```

Comment: use switch case statement

Comment: Why are you adding spaces before and after the title?

Comment: Because apparently `strpos` wont match if the string starts with what im trying to find.

Comment: @MikeMeade: It would but it would return `0` so your comparison would have to be `!== false` instead of just `!`.

Comment: @MikeMeade Nonsense. It will just return `0`, because it is starts at index `0`. You just have to take that into account, like `if (strpos(...) !== false)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one solution:

```
$imgsrc = 'default.png';
for ( $percent=100; $percent>0; $percent--) {
    if(strpos($this->escape($title), $percent . '% off') !== false){
        $imgsrc = $percent . 'percentoff.png';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! just the ticket!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what `$title` contains, you can still match the percent number with a regular expression:

```
<?php

if(preg_match('/^([1-9][0-9]?|100)% off/', $this->escape($title), $matches)) {
  $imgsrc = $matches[1] . 'percentoff.png';
} else {
  $imgsrc = 'default.png';
}
```

Comment: I may add a restriction to verify that $matches[1] falls between a boundary such as 1 and 100, otherwise 100000percentof.png could be used.

Comment: @Danbopes: Yes, it depends on where `$title` comes from and whether it can contain out of range number. Mike didn't specify that.

Comment: He mentioned 50+ lines, which implies as restriction on the number of possibilities it could be.

Comment: OK, 1-100 range added.

Comment: Nice, I really like this solution. I would have added manual if/else statements. (But this is much better)